# Python Flickr API kit: How to restrict the number of results?

Tags: python, api, flickr

The [documentation](http://stuvel.eu/media/flickrapi-docs/apidoc/) says

```
walk_set(self, photoset_id, per_page=50, ...)
source code 
Other arguments can be passed, as documented in the flickr.photosets.getPhotos API call in the Flickr API documentation, except for page because all pages will be returned eventually.
```

If I just want 20 results, how can I do that?  Otherwise, its just keep on running and getting the data

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described on the [getPhotos](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photosets.getPhotos.html), you can do:

```
walk_set(self, photoset_id, per_page=20, page=1)
```

Comment: This is actually _not_ the proper solution. `walk_set` was meant to iterate over all photos in a set. All you change by passing `per_page` is the number of photos it fetches in one batch.

Answer (score 0):

If you want only 20 photos, don't use `walk_set`, as it is intended to iterate over all photos in a set. Use `flickr.photosets.getPhotos` directly, and specify `per_page=20` and `page=1`.